# Debugger not gaining access to library code (GDCM)

Tags: c++, debugging, gdcm

I am sure this is a trivial question for most. I am building code based on C++ GDCM (GrassRoot DICOM) library. Interestingly, using GDB, I am unable to traverse into the library headers. Is there an option which i need to turn on during the GDCM build process?

Comment: It needs to be built with debug-information enabled. For GCC use the flag `-g` to enable it. This is usually the default for libraries built with the autoconfig system (`./configure; make`), just make sure the debug information is not stripped when installing.

Answer (score 1):

GDCM used CMake build system. Simply set: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug. Done.

Comment: Thanks. Mostlibraries have debug symbols but GDCMDICOMDIRGenerator does not 'step in', for example. In any case, I have built my project successfully so not too worried about not being able to step in